# Customizing the output of Stemming

Tags: java, stemming

I've been using Snowball Porter2 for stemming. I don't want the root form as output.For eg., the Porter2 produces "Emergenc" after stemming "Emergencies". I want "Emergency" instead. Will someone please point direction how to achieve the result? The desired output would have to produce some sensible meaning. Porter2 often produces desired results but still ways to refine the result would be thankful. Thanks in forward.

Other example would be:
Services - Servic (preferred output is "Service")

Comment: This is how a stemmer is supposed to work. What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: "Emergencies" -> "Emergency" isn't stemming, it's morphological analysis.  A stemmer can't _change_ the ending, it can only chop off more or fewer characters.

Comment: @Zutty, actually we are doing project on companies name similarity checking project.We also check for translation/transliteration stuffs in consideration while comparing.So we are not going for root words rather trying to find base words with sensible meanings.

Comment: @IanRoberts thanks for the reply, I'm just wondering if "services-service" was possible,Porter2 gives result for "potatoes-potato".We'll consider morphological analysis.